# How NodeJS reads the data from the Kernel buffer (TCP buffer/memory)?

Tags: node.js, http, tcp, stream, kernel

I know that when TCP connection is made and the receiver receive a package it does two things:

- to **acknowledge** the sender that the package is received so the sender could free its memory from the sender kernel buffer.
- to **store this data in receiver kernel buffer** (receiver TCP buffer/memory) where **NodeJS needs to read it** in order to be released/flushed from the receiver kernel memory and moved to the NodeJS memory/buffer.

**Question 1)** How is NodeJS reading the data from this Kernel buffer? Because somehow this data becomes available to the `response.body.on("readable", ()=>{response.body.read()})` readable stream. How did it get there? What triggered the push from the receiver kernel memory to this receiver NodeJS readable stream (`response.body`)?

**Question 2)** Is the receiver kernel buffer or whatever is doing the push going to wait for "drain" event from the NodeJS readable stream (`response.body`) or it will push no matter what?

I tried to find information about it but without success. So please help me in order to understand the entire **"Sender NodeJS App -> Sender TCP Buffer -> Receiver TCP Buffer -> Receiver NodeJS App"** process.

Comment: 1. There was no push. There was a read() invocation which *pulled* data from the kernel to the application. 2. Once read, the kernel data is gone.

Comment: 1. Can you show me where in the source code of nodejs and c++ this binding happens? Because without proof we could only guess whats the real situation.   2. does a single read() flush all the packages in the kernel memory or it flushes only a single package from the kernel memory? From what I saw one read() flushes only one kernel package with size of 64kb which is the maximum package size in TCP.

Comment: 1. What binding? I am talking about what happens between the kernel and the BSD sockets API, which node.js has to call one way or the other. No proof required, it's well-known, and documented in manuals and standard texts. 2. The buffer is a data stream. *Packets,* (not 'packages'), no longer exist. A `read()` consumes some or all of that stream. 3. There is no such thing as 'the maximum package size in TCP'. There is a maximum *segment* size, but it can be far larger than 64k. Unless you're slow in reading, the most you will get out of a single `read()` is about 1500 bytes.